# Syntax error in MySQL INSERT statement with TIME datatypes

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add records to a MySQL table, but I keep getting a syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO `lwljhb_lwl_matches` (id, league_seasons_id, schedule_id, playoff_round, scheduled_week_number, date_played, winner_id, loser_id, forfeit, forfeit_reason, match_begin_time, match_end_time)

VALUES  (,14,,0,1,2018-04-15,52,87,0,,'14:55:00','17:41:00');
```

The id column is autoincrementing, the match_begin_time and match_end_time fields are TIMEs.
Can anyone point out my stupid mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* specify *something* for all columns.

```
INSERT INTO `lwljhb_lwl_matches` (id, ...)
  VALUES  (NULL, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a column with no data you must put `null` unless the column can't be null. this is your correct statemen

```
INSERT INTO `lwljhb_lwl_matches` (id, league_seasons_id, schedule_id, playoff_round, scheduled_week_number, date_played, winner_id, loser_id, forfeit, forfeit_reason, match_begin_time, match_end_time) VALUES  (null,14,null,0,1,2018-04-15,52,87,0,null,'14:55:00','17:41:00');
```